# pushing string[array] instead of 'string' to array in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code

```
let array = [];
const datas = [
 'name1',
 'name2',
 'name3',
];
 
async function getData() {
    datas.forEach((data) => {
      let myData = data.name;
      if(!array.includes(myData)){
        array.push(myData);
      }
    })

    let result = await array;
    
    console.log('Result', result);
};

getData();
```

that returns an array that contains strings like

```
['name1','name2', 'name3']
```

And I would like to make all of the `array` indexes arrays themselves, so I can later push data in the array's indexes, like

```
['name1': [], 'name2': [], 'name3': []]
```

Does somebody know how to do this in plain javascript ?

Comment: `[name1[], name2[], name3[]]` isn't valid JS, do you mean using an object instead of the outer array, e.g. `{name1: [], name2: [], name3: []}`?

Comment: Why `async`/`await`? `await`ing an array doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Andreas I need the array to be fully treated before being available. If I don't async/await, the array can be console.logged before being treated and the length would be 0.

Comment: @sp00m I just edited my post, maybe it is a bit clearer to you ?

Comment: No, not with the script in your question. There's nothing asynchronous in it that would require to "wait" for something

Comment: @Andreas Oh right, that was a first step, thanks.

Comment: `['name1': [], 'name2': [], 'name3': []]` still isn't valid. I you really want an array, you could go with `['name1', [], 'name2', [], 'name3', []]`, but that will be a bit of a pain to deal with. What's wrong with using an object instead of the outer array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood well, seems you need something like this

```
let obj = {};
const datas = [
 'name1',
 'name2',
 'name3',
];
 
function getData() {
    datas.forEach((data) => {
      obj[data] = []
    })

    console.log('Result', obj);

};

getData();
```

```
Result { name1: [], name2: [], name3: [] }
```

tip: Array keys can be only indexes

Answer (score 0):

You could have an object instead of an array and add each name to the object as a key like this:

```
let obj = {};
const datas = [
 'name1',
 'name2',
 'name3',
];
 
function getData() {
  datas.forEach((data) => {
    if(!obj[data]){
      obj[data] = [];
    }
  })
  console.log(obj);
}

getData();
```

this would give you an object like

```
{
  name1: [],
  name2: [],
  name3: []
}
```

Each name would need to be unique.

If you want it to return an array, you could build an array of objects like this:

```
let array = [];
const datas = [
 'name1',
 'name2',
 'name3',
];
 
function getData() {
  datas.forEach((data) => {
    array.push({
      name: data,
      data: []
    });
  })
  console.log(array);
}

getData();
```

Which would give you an array like

```
[{
  data: [],
  name: "name1"
}, {
  data: [],
  name: "name2"
}, {
  data: [],
  name: "name3"
}]
```